# How can I make my Discord bot change its status every 10 seconds or so? (Including things like "Listening to", "Playing" and "Watching")

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Please tell me how should I do that.
Here is my code that dont works:

```
let activity = ["`${client.users.size} commands | ><help`, {type: "LISTENING"}", "`on ${client.guilds.size} servers | ><help`, {type: "PLAYING"}
client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1); // generates a random number between 1 and the length of the activities array list (in this case 5).
        client.user.setActivity(activities_list[index]); // sets bot's activities to one of the phrases in the arraylist.
    }, 10000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have a problem with the quotation in an array, try this:

```
let activityTypes = ['PLAYING','STREAMING','LISTENING','WATCHING']
let randomType = activityTypes[Math.floor((Math.random()*activityTypes.length))]

setInterval(async ()=>{
    await client.user.setActivity('Your text here.', { type: randomType })
},10000)
```

But keep in mind, 10 seconds will probably hit the discord API rate limit.